# Как победить жор памяти для php скрипта

Tags: php, wordpress, json

Есть некий фид в формате json, его должен обработать мой php скрипт. Фид огромен, 150Мб и более 50 000 записей в нём с параметрами. В таком виде, конечно, его обработать очень трудно. Его даже блокнот открывает с трудом. Я его делю на файлы, могу разделить насколько угодно. Например, если на 300 частей, то файлы уже получаются небольшими. Алгоритм такой:

```
  for($i=0; $i<300; $i++){ //300 - количество файлов - частей
   
$feed = json_decode(file_get_contents(get_template_directory() . '/feed/feed-'.$i.'.json'), true); //получаю содержимое файла
foreach ($feed as $flat): //далее идёт обработка содержимого, endforeach, endfor
```

Смотрю через top и не пойму, почему процесс httpd разрастается по памяти. По идее, переменная feed каждый раз в новой итерации for заменяется на новое содержимое следующего файла и примерное количество занятой памяти должно быть одно и тоже. Но нет, объём потребляемой памяти растёт непрерывно. Прочитал про file_get_contents, после неё никак закрывать файл не нужно, да и нет ID файла который можно было бы закрыть. Не важно делю ли я фид на 40 частей или 300, скрипт прорабатывает определённое время, обрабатывает несколько файлов и умирает. Как победить жор памяти?

Comment: несколько не ясно. у вас был большой json, как вы его разделили на мелкие? зы: сколько это пямяти оно юзает? (закрыватеся обработав несколько файлов из за тайм лимита,  или кривого разбиения?) зы: сборщик мусора пхп не обязательно будет очищать память сразу, когда переменная освобождена.

Comment: дайте больше кода. скорее всего после того как вы вычитали, вы обрабатываете данные (тобиш куда то сохраняете дальше и манипулируете ими). Предполагаю что проблема не в этих строках, а где-то дальше

Comment: для больших файлов обычно вообще юзают потоковые парсеры, это избавляет от долгой загрузки в память исходного файла и построения дерева целиком. Но надо понимать, что тут вы должны представлять структуру данных, чтоб корректно его обрабатывать. зы: как верно заметили выше,данные то разобранные вы куда складываете, не это место память ест?

Comment: Пробовал после endforeach перед endfor делать unset($feed) чтоб точно освобождать память занятую под переменную - никак не помогает. Как заставить сборщик мусора работать пооперативнее?

Comment: ну и так допишу. После обработки каждого файла попробуйте `unset($feed);`. Ну и еще в добавок можно принудительно почистить (ЗАРАНЕЕ ИЗБАВИВШИСЬ ОТ ВСЕХ ССЫЛОК)`gc_collect_cycles()`.

Comment: Данные я не накапливаю ни в каком массиве, никуда не складываю ни в какую переменную глобальную. В каждом цикле foreach  я получаю инфу с фида, сравниваю её актуальность и если что, закидываю обновлённую инфу в базу mysql средствами WP. Всё инкапсулировано в функции, поэтому каждый вызов в итерации foreach изолирован, заканчивается цикл foreach - заканчивается инфа из старого файла, берём новый в цикле for

Comment: @teran все таймауты увеличены и PHP и Апач и NGINX. Скрипт сейчас работает пока не кончается свободная память, потом начинается дикий своп на серваке, ну и после этого видимо пока кто-то из связки апач+nginx не ляжет.

Comment: Я извиняюсь, а при чем здесь НTTPD вообще?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Всё, всем огромное спасибо за помощь. Действительно была проблема в коде. Постоянно выполнялся один запрос к БД при каждой итерации, убрал запрос из цикла, сохранил данные в массив, теперь сравниваю данные со значением массива - память не жрёт от слова совсем!

Comment: В таком случае отметьте, пожалуйста, свой ответ как принятый

Comment: @dgopadakak зачем? Кому поможет ответ "ну я в общем там один запрос убрал"?

Answer (score 0):

Для таких задач придуманы очереди. Обработчик очереди смотрит на размер используемой памяти и лимит процессорного времени, и если они начинают подходить к концу, то запускается новый асинхронный процесс php.

Простейшая реализация: [Background Processing](https://github.com/kagg-design/wp-background-processing)

[Пример](https://github.com/mihdan/cyr2lat/tree/master/src/php/BackgroundProcesses) простейшей реализации.

Расширенная реализация: [Action Scheduler](https://actionscheduler.org/)

Comment: Это всё должно выполняться через WP_cron, я привязан к WooCommerce, поэтому всё должно выполняться в среде WP, к сожалению

Comment: Всё, что я привёл в ответе, выполняется в среде WP.

Comment: Более того, Action Scheduler встроен в WooCommerce и вовсю там используется.